# Translating Foxpro into TSQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, visual-foxpro

I couldn't think of a better title, so if you have one, feel free to edit my post.

I have this:

```
SELECT payor.payor_cd, payor.desc, .f. AS selected ;
    FROM dbfs\payor ;
    WHERE broker ;
    INTO CURSOR 'TempPay_RO' ;
    ORDER BY payor_cd
```

This is what I have when I tried to translate this into T-SQL:

```
select
     payor_cd
     desc
from
    payor
order by
    payor_cd;
```

Here are my questions:

1) What is `.f` ? There is nothing prior to this foxpro query that describes what it is.

2) What is meant by the `where broker` part? `Where broker` is what? `Broker` is just a column in the table.

Comment: If memory serves .f. is FALSE  Is broker a boolean ?

Comment: Yes, broker is a column in the database that takes 1 and 0 values, so where broker means where broker = 1 (or whatever means true) by default?

Comment: I understand that .f is false, but are we creating a constant that is just ".f" values?

Comment: That seems correct to me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In SQL Server context

```
select payor_cd
      ,[desc]
      ,Selected = convert(bit,0)
from  payor
Where Broker = 1
order by payor_cd
```